# Cannot update record with EF, error when attaching

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am receiving this error:

> "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: 
>   The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship."

when attempting to update my model from the front end. I did some research and saw a post that said I should null out my navigation properties to prevent this so I did but no luck. I have also tried reaching out and grabbing all the navigation properties and fully populating them so I have the full object, this too did not work.

I am using a really nice "[generic repository](http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/)" which handles the state changes and everything for me. When it goes into the update method it is attaching the record and blows up when doing so.

Here is the code that is setting up the object in my WebApi controller.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(ProductModel product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);

    var shopId = _uow.Repository<Shop>().GetShopIdByUserId("90f36c26-9b28-464d-869f-378015ae8f0c"); //work

    product.ShopId = shopId;

    var newProduct = Mapper.Map<Product>(product);
    newProduct.Category = null;

    try
    {
        _uow.Repository<Product>().Update(newProduct);
        _uow.Save();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

This is the Repositories implementation for update. Id prefer not to touch this as it is part of the generic repository framework I am using.

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    _dbSet.Attach(entity); // **Blows up here**
    ((IObjectState)entity).State = ObjectState.Modified;
}
```

I am using WebApi v2, EF 6.

Edit:

I had a list of test data that should not have been sent to EF, i nulled it out and it works now. Funny how you can look at something 100x but not have it click until someone tells you to do the same thing lol!

Comment: are you sure all foreign keys in your entity object are satisfied?

Comment: omg.. you know i nulled out all the navigation properties, but this is test data and i don't have image uploads yet but i populated the list with test data. since they don't actually exist i wasn't thinking about having to clear them out... thanks @kostyan. its funny i was making sure but your comment triggered it for me lol